# python webscraper, requiring a dynamic object array

Tags: python

I have compiled the following code that extracts information from pages defined in the `url` object. Instead of writing down each URL. The code works in itself, however for my actual use case I have a list of 50 URLs that I would like to the script to go through. The URLs all have the same structure https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/**Nickname** and I would want to store them in another object for the script to go through, but I seem to be unable to do that. Does anyone have an idea how I would achieve this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
urls = ['https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/S1mple', 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/M0NESY', 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/Dexter']
players = []
for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
    stammdaten = dict( (e.text, e.find_next_sibling('div').text) for e in soup.select('.infobox-description'))
    stammdaten['nickname'] = url.split('/')[-1]
    players.append(stammdaten)
    #print(players)

#creating a player DataFrame
playerdf = pd.DataFrame(players, columns =['nickname','Born:','Role:'])
print(playerdf)

#creating a dataframe
index = [1]
stammdatendf = pd.DataFrame(stammdaten, columns = ['nickname', 'Role:','Born:'], index=index)
#print(stammdatendf)

#exporting data into Excel
playerdf.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what the issue is. You want to append different nicknames to a static string?

You could use a list comprehension to generate a list of urls.

```
player_names = ["S1mple", "M0NESY", "Dexter"]
url = "https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/"
player_urls = [url+player_name for player_name in player_names]
#['https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/S1mple', 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/M0NESY', 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/Dexter']
```